# Emprego da palavra "Doutor(a)" // Use of the word "Doutor(a)"

Tags: uso-de-palavras

De tempos em tempos, volta a dúvida: quem é Doutor/Doutora? O seu uso deveria ser exclusivo para médicos? E os cirurgiões-dentistas, os advogados, os engenheiros, os enfermeiros, os fisioterapeutas, os farmacêuticos? "Doutor" não é apenas quem defende tese em Curso de Doutorado? Afinal, "doutor" é título ou forma de tratamento? Quem/quais profissionais podem ser considerados "doutor"?

Existem diversas discussões na internet sobre o assunto, mas acho bacana ver também algo do gênero aqui na rede.

Answer (score 14):

Efetivamente, o título de **doutor** nos tempos modernos é dedicado a pessoas com o grau para tal, sejam doutores de medicina (*medicinae doctor*) ou doutores de filosofia (*doctor philosophiae*). Nessas situações, devemos tratar essa pessoa por Doutor. Acrescento que o processo de Bolonha rege esta atribuição de título, e este [foi oficialmente adotado por Portugal em 2008](http://www.dges.mctes.pt/NR/rdonlyres/AE6762DF-1DBF-40C0-B194-E3FAA9516D79/2366/DL107_2008.pdf).

Contudo, em Portugal, e potencialmente também no Brasil, desenvolveu-se o costume (um tanto lamentável) de tratar pessoas com uma qualificação inferior ao doutoramento como **senhor doutor** (**Sr. Dr.**), ou até mesmo só **doutor** (**Dr.**), podendo ser aplicado até a quem possui apenas uma licenciatura. Aos engenheiros e arquitetos, já é mais comum (e mais correto) serem tratados por **senhor engenheiro** (**Sr. Eng.**). As pessoas formadas para o ensino também são **professores** (**Prof.**), podendo ser combinado com *doutor* quando se trata de um professor com o devido grau (**professor doutor**).

Indicar mais do que isto pode tornar-se mais parcial, tendo em conta a linha vaga que foi estabelecida pela língua ao longo do tempo. Poderá ainda ser possível identificar mais exceções de profissões de cujo graduado não é tratado por doutor (como **enfermeiro**, **Enf**), mas poderá também depender da cultura e da opinião de cada um. Nos casos mais vagos, tratar um licenciado ou mestre por **senhor** (**Sr**) não estará errado. O mesmo se pode dizer para o caso de ser tratado por doutor, embora apenas pelo facto de ser um costume fortemente infundido na língua.

Comment: Eu dei +1 mas não tinha visto o "é mais correto" da edição. É tão correto chamar a uma pessoa licenciada em medicina de doutor (titulo) como chamar a uma pessoa licenciada em engenharia de informática de engenheiro (titulo) ou como chamar a um pintor de Pintor (não usual). Não se pode é confundir com os graus académicos. Até porque, na verdade, o que se usa são títulos e raramente se usa o grau académico de doutor, só quando já têm o titulo de licenciado, como *Sr. Doutor Eng.* ou *Professor Doutor*.

Comment: +1 por "lamentável hábito"

Answer (score 9):

## dou·tor |ô|

> substantivo masculino
>
> 1. Indivíduo que recebeu o maior grau universitário, com direito a usar as insígnias de borla e capelo.
> 2. Homem douto em ciências ou letras.
> 3. [Por extensão]  Bacharel formado.
> 4. [Religião]  Dogmatizador arguto.
> 5. [Informal]  Pessoa ignorante e pretensiosa.
> 6. Bacio.
>
> "doutor", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/doutor [consultado em
> 27-07-2015].

---

*Doutor* tanto em Portugal como no Brasil é um **grau académico** atribuído, ou seja, quem detém um diploma de doutoramento é **doutor**.

Usa-se também **doutor** como **titulo**, no caso dos médicos e advogados, por exemplo.

Na escrita, costuma-se usar **dr.** no caso de se referir a **titulo**, e **doutor** no caso de se referir ao **grau académico**.

Fonte: [Doutor, dr. e licenciado](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/doutor-dr-e-licenciado/179)

Comment: *Já agora, detesto esse tipo de títulos como **doutor**, **dr.**, **engenheiro**, etc. Acho que toda a gente tem o seu nome, eu sou Jorge, não sou Engenheiro Jorge.* 

*Antigamente, usava-se muito isto para diferenciar as pessoas, as de alto nível e a plebe. Acho que nos tempos que correm, tantos lutamos por igualdade que não se justifica de forma alguma usar este tipo de títulos.*

Comment: Este não é o sítio para combater ideais, Jorge, por melhor que este seja. Além disso, creio que o fundo da questão está no motivo pelo qual pessoas sem o grau de doutor são na mesma tratadas por _Dr._ ou _Sr. Dr._.

Comment: @E_net4 também não é minha intenção debater nada aqui. Dei apenas a minha opinião depois de ter respondido concretamente a pergunta. Não vejo qual é o mal. E não vou apagar, acho que faz bem a todos que leiam isto saberem esta opinião.

Comment: @E_net4 as pessoas sem grau de doutor são tratadas por dr. por terem uma licenciatura. Os engenheiros e professores são apenas licenciados então era "importante" existir também um título para os demais licenciados, ou seja, doutor.

Answer (score 6):

Como título acadêmico, para o qual é necessário defender tese perante banca examinadora, dentre outras obrigações, doutor é raramente utilizado no Brasil. Em geral, apenas em apresentações públicas em que um breve resumo do apresentador é feito.

Porém, doutor também é pronome informal de tratamento de algumas profissões, como médicos, engenheiros e advogados. Nesse caso, não há regra. Utiliza-se a pronome doutor/a "quando se quer demonstrar respeito e/ou subserviência", pois já vi até pessoas sem formação acadêmica serem chamadas de doutores apenas por inspirarem medo e respeito em uma determinada comunidade. Funciona mais ou menos como o "Coronel", que, apesar de ser uma posição militar, também é usado para designar alguém que detenha o controle de uma determinada região, em geral pelo uso da força.

Há outros casos ainda mais incomuns do emprego da palavra doutor, nos quais uma pessoa pode ser chamada de doutor, sem cair nos dois casos anteriores. Ressalto o caso de "doutor honoris causa", no qual alguma universidade pode (creio que outros órgãos também possam) outorgar o título a uma pessoa, mesmo que não possua formação acadêmica. Em geral esse título é outorgado a alguém que tenha dado contribuição significativa em determinada área, porém não cumpriu todos os ritos acadêmicos.

Answer (score 3):

No Brasil, doutor pode ser um título

- conferido a quem defendeu tese de doutorado em uma universidade.
- conferido a juízes e delegados **por disposição legal**.
- concedido **por cortesia** aos que se diplomaram em curso superior, especialmente em medicina.
- concedido a qualquer um **como indicativo de respeito** na hierarquia social.

Fonte: [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/doutor/)

Answer (score 0):

A utilização da abreviatura Dr. é um título aplicado aos Licenciados, isto é, quem tem o grau académico respectivo à Licenciatura, para a diferenciar dos Doutorados, ou seja, quem possui o grau académico referente ao Doutoramento e a quem se atribuiu o título de Doutor por extenso, independentemente, da área de estudos, ou Prof. Dr. abreviado se for Investigador. Um Prof. Doutor por extenso já é um título que se atribui ao mais alto cargo, ou seja, a quem possui uma Cátedra.

Dr. - Licenciaturas em geral;
Eng. - Licenciatura na área da Engenharia (a quem se pode atribuir também o título de Dr. abreviado);
Professor - Docência;
Mestre - Mestrados;
Doutor / Prof. Dr. - Doutoramentos;
Prof. Doutor - Professor Catedrático.

Por tradição, chamam os médicos de Doutor, mas a verdade é que só o são se tiverem um Doutoramento, caso contrário, são Dr. ou Mestre, se forem detentores de Licenciatura ou Mestrado, ou Prof. Doutor se forem Professores Catedráticos, como acontece em qualquer outra área profissional (Direito, Engenharias, Enfermagem, Medicina, Comunicação, Audiovisuais, Educação, Psicologia, Arquitectura, Design, etc...).

Também há quem diga que a abreviatura “Dr.” não existe, mas isso é um enorme equívoco. A abreviatura existe sim e é atribuída, precisamente, nas situações mencionadas. Todas estas informações apenas se referem aos títulos aplicados em Portugal.